# How do I persist TListView.Items (TListItems) in the external file (or TStream)?

Tags: delphi, persistence, vcl

It has something to do with `TListItems.DefineProperties`... Here is my writing attempt:

```
  Stream := TFileStream.Create('ListView.dat', fmCreate);
  Writer := TWriter.Create(Stream, 4096);
  TListItemsHelper(ListView.Items).DefineProperties(Writer);
  Writer.Free;
  Stream.Free;
```

... and it apparently works, but reading code

```
  Stream := TFileStream.Create('ListView.dat', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  Reader := TReader.Create(Stream, 4096);
  TListItemsHelper(ListView.Items).DefineProperties(Reader);
  Reader.Free;
  Stream.Free;
```

... does not populate Items with file contents. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: try `Writer.WriteRootComponent(ListView)` and `Reader.ReadRootComponent(ListView)`

Comment: @kobik: If you make that an answer, I'll upvote it, because that is exactly what is missing after the DefineProperties statements. Without them it seems to work, but that just means no errors occur. With them data is actually written to and read from the file.

Comment: @MarjanVenema, I still didn't see any response from the OP, so I'll leave that as a comment for now.

Answer (score 4):

```
procedure ListViewSaveToStream(aListView: TListView; Stream: TStream);
var
  i: integer;
  aItem: TListItem;
  n: longint;
  buffer: smallint;
  b: boolean;
  s: string;
begin
  Stream.Size := 0;
  n := aListView.Items.Count;
  Stream.Write(n, SizeOf(n));

  if n > 0 then
  begin
    if aListView.ItemFocused <> nil then
      n := aListView.ItemFocused.Index
    else
      n := -1;
    Stream.Write(n, SizeOf(n));

    for i := 0 to aListView.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin
      aItem := aListView.Items[i];

      s := aItem.Caption;
      buffer := Length(s);
      Stream.Write(buffer, SizeOf(buffer));
      if buffer > 0 then
        Stream.Write(s[1], buffer);

      s := aItem.SubItems.CommaText;
      n := Length(s);
      Stream.Write(n, SizeOf(n));
      if n > 0 then
        Stream.Write(s[1], n);

      b := aItem.Checked;
      Stream.Write(b, SizeOf(b));

      buffer := aItem.ImageIndex;
      Stream.Write(buffer, SizeOf(buffer));

      buffer := aItem.StateIndex;
      Stream.Write(buffer, SizeOf(buffer));

      buffer := aItem.OverlayIndex;
      Stream.Write(buffer, SizeOf(buffer));

      buffer := aItem.Indent;
      Stream.Write(buffer, SizeOf(buffer));

      n := integer(aItem.Data);
      Stream.Write(n, SizeOf(n));

      b := aItem.Selected;
      Stream.Write(b, SizeOf(b));

    end;
  end;
end;

procedure ListViewVLoadFromStream(aListView: TListView; Stream: TStream);

var
  i: integer;
  aItem: TListItem;
  cnt, n, ItemFocusedIndex: longint;
  buffer: smallint;
  b: boolean;
  s: string;
begin
  aListView.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    aListView.Items.Clear;

    Stream.Position := 0;

    Stream.Read(cnt, SizeOf(cnt));
    if cnt > 0 then
    begin
      aListView.AllocBy := cnt;

      Stream.Read(ItemFocusedIndex, SizeOf(ItemFocusedIndex));

      for i := 0 to cnt - 1 do
      begin
        aItem := aListView.Items.Add;

        Stream.Read(buffer, SizeOf(buffer));
        if buffer > 0 then
        begin
          SetLength(s, buffer);
          Stream.Read(s[1], buffer);
          aItem.Caption := s;
        end;

        Stream.Read(n, SizeOf(n));
        if n > 0 then
        begin
          SetLength(s, n);
          Stream.Read(s[1], n);
          aItem.SubItems.CommaText := s;
        end;

        Stream.Read(b, SizeOf(b));
        aItem.Checked := b;

        Stream.Read(buffer, SizeOf(buffer));
        aItem.ImageIndex := buffer;

        Stream.Read(buffer, SizeOf(buffer));
        aItem.StateIndex := buffer;

        Stream.Read(buffer, SizeOf(buffer));
        aItem.OverlayIndex := buffer;

        Stream.Read(buffer, SizeOf(buffer));
        aItem.Indent := buffer;


        Stream.Read(n, SizeOf(n));
        aItem.Data := TObject(n);

        Stream.Read(b, SizeOf(b));

      end;
    end;


  finally
    aListView.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure LVSaveToFile(const Filename: string; aListView: TListView);
var
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmCreate);
  try
    ListViewSaveToStream(aListView, FS);
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure ListViewLoadFromFile(const Filename: string; aListView: TListView);

var
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  if FileExists(Filename) then
  begin
    FS := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
    try
      ListViewVLoadFromStream(aListView, FS);
    finally
      FS.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

// Example...
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LVSaveToFile('C:\temp\test.sav', ListView1);
end;

procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListViewLoadFromFile('C:\temp\test.sav', ListView2);

end;
```